# How to create a Chronicle Queue with Hourly rolling store files(cq4)

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

Hi I'm new to Chronicle Queue I have some doubts,

1. I want to create a ChronicleQueue with hourly rolling store files How can I create one. I creates the writer as follows,

   ```
   ChronicleQueue queue = ChronicleQueueBuilder.single(chroniclePath).build();
   ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();
   ```
2. Also I want to delete the files after the consumer completes reading, can I create a writer as follows for the same,

   ```
   ChronicleQueue queue = ChronicleQueueBuilder.single(chroniclePath).storeFileListener(new StoreFileListener() {

           @Override
           public void onReleased(int cycle, File file) {

               if (file != null) {
                   try {
                       file.delete();
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       //log
                   }
               }
           }
       }).build();
   ```

I want to know whether I'm doing in the proper way in this case.

3. Do we need to store the cycle number also in the reader for reading after a restart. Currently I'm storing index the only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the roll cycle in the builder

```
ChronicleQueue queue = ChronicleQueueBuilder.single(chroniclePath)
                                            .rollCycle(RollCycles.HOURLY)
                                            .build();
ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();
```

The listener can be used for deleting old files.

Typically, you only need to store the index for the reader (the cycle is part of the index)